# How to integrate Invisible ReCaptcha with Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a Result Search Flask Application in Python.
Input is the roll number by the user and output is result.
I've made the search system, but now I need to implement ReCaptcha to prevent Scraping.
I've got the site key, secret key and also placed the HTML button. Now, how should I implement the Invisible ReCaptcha logic/conditions in the Flask App?
Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I was also struggling with it the past months, just been working on it again and it seems the package has been recently updated:

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-GoogleReCaptcha/

-> from **flask_google_recaptcha** import **GoogleReCaptcha**

On my project, either it's not working or is really well invisible...

Looking forward to hearing your feedback!

Anaïs